# Posting information and retrieving results using Ajax

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to using (Ajax) PHP or Javascript,  Post information to http://en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/vortaro.pl  then read the results back (Not from lernu.net).

I am trying to learn Ajax, PHP + Javascript, Nobody there know's how to help me.  I would very much like doing this without touching Lernu's code,  So if there is a way to do it all on my code, that would be great!

Comment: Probably because the server-side script was written in Perl

Comment: Which browsers do you want to support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You maybe able to do a simple post to your url with jquery in following ways:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/vortaro.pl",
   data: "name=John&age=21",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Posted to server: " + msg );
     // you may additionally call other javascript methods here to do modifications to your page based on your request
   }
 });
```

Jquery is an excellent framework for javascript and I would highly recommend using it for most of your functionality. You might want to readup a bit about javascript and then start up with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to proxy the request due to browsers preventing cross-domain ajax calls.

You can either do this with a PHP page on your site or configure url rewrite rules for your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a PHP script in your domain that forwards your POST to `http://en.lernu.net/cgi-bin/vortaro.pl`, then forwards their response back to the client.

You can then [send an AJAX POST to your server with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: Well thank you,  I have read how to do a php redirect page,  But a google search on php forwarding does not come up with anything useful.  can you please be a little more detail. maybe a link or some code,  Thank you very much